# How to skip duplicate labels in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a graph that I want to put labels on from a file that looks like this

```
20151019,labela
20151020,labela
20151021,labela
20151022,labelb
20151023,labelb
```

But I only want the label shown if its different from the previous label. (so only put labels on 20151019 and 20151022) Currently I have to pre-process the file to remove the duplicates. Is there a way to do this within gnuplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, preprocessing the file is the best option. That can also be done on-the-fly, like

```
plot '< script.sh file' ...
```

Because you can use this kind of preprocessing, gnuplot has only limited support for such data manipulation.

In your case you can use a trick: register all labels in a string, delimited by some characters which don't appear in the labels. Then you can use `strstrt` to lookup if a label already appeared, and skip the point otherwise:

```
set datafile separator ','
set timefmt '%Y%m%d'
set xdata time

s = ''
known(c) = (strstrt(s, '@@'.strcol(c).'@@') > 0)
plot 'file.dat' using (use = known(2), s = s . (use ? '@@'.strcol(2).'@@ ' : ''), use ? timecolumn(1) : 1/0):(0):2 with labels
```

I didn't know, which y coordinates you have, so I used `0`.

Comment: New to gnuplot, I did not know about running scripts from within the program. So what worked out for me was `plot '< uniq -s 8 file' ...`

Comment: That's definitely the better choice!